# how can use GetListSomething() with stream

Tags: java, spring, dto

```
    package com.eukolos.restaurant.dto;
```

import com.eukolos.restaurant.model.Table;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AllTableResponseConverter {

```
public AllTableResponse convert(Table table ) {

    AllTableResponse allTableResponse = new AllTableResponse();
    allTableResponse.setId(table.getId());
    allTableResponse.setNumber(table.getNumber());
allTableResponse.setAccountList(table.getAccountList().stream().map(AccountIdResponseConverter::convert).collect(Collectors.toList()));//

    return allTableResponse;
}
```

}`
getAccountList() cant use with stream
how can i handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you test this code below? Is this what you want to achieve?

```
@Component 
public class AllTableResponseConverter { 

 public AllTableResponse convert(Table table ) {
        
        List<AccountIdResponseConverter> convertedAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
        
        AllTableResponse allTableResponse = new AllTableResponse();
        allTableResponse.setId(table.getId());
        allTableResponse.setNumber(table.getNumber());
        for(Table t : table.getAccountList()) {
                AccountIdResponseConverter converter = new AccountIdResponseConverter();
                convertedAccounts.add(converter.convert(t));
        }       
        allTableResponse.setAccountList(convertedAccounts);
    
        return allTableResponse;
    }
}
```